# Convert String to Byte Array without Encoding?

Tags: java

So I have a string with Binary Data like this:

```
String lob = "ÿØÿà...";
```

I really have no control over this so I have to take it as it is.  So I need to convert this as an InputStream without changing it, if I just do:

```
getBytes()
```

It will use the default encoding, how do I do this without any encoding or modification?

EdIT:

I can't fix this from the source.   I do know the original data is a image loaded from HTML GET, but I don't know how it was encoded during transfer .  All I have right now is a really long string and I need to convert it back and save it into a database.

Comment: could you not just set utf-8 and go from there?

Comment: @Woot4Moo: Not if the OP is trying to reverse the encoding performed by some earlier step...

Comment: The problem is that you may already be screwed; try and see whether `.indexOf('\ufffd')` is -1; if it is you _may_ turn it back to the original data, if not, SOL!

Comment: Hi @fge I ran .indexOf('\ufffd') and it is not -1, how do I salvage this situation?

Comment: Well, you can't... U+FFFD is Unicode's replacement character, and it is the character used by an encoding process when the byte sequence cannot be converted to a character. You need to "negotiate" with the source and tell them to fix the problem, that is, send the bytes directly...

Comment: If we know it is unicode.  Why can't i just decode it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no such concept as a conversion like that without encoding. You're converting between *characters* and *bytes* - those aren't the same thing, so a conversion is required, and the form of the conversion is precisely the encoding. Anything which claims to be converting without using an encoding is just assuming some specific encoding without necessarily knowing they're doing so.

If you want to get the original binary data, you need to find out what encoding was used to convert the bytes into a string to start with. You *may* find that ISO-8859-1 will work, but you really need to check.

At the same time, you should try *very* hard to change it to use something like base64. Converting arbitrary binary data to text and back like this is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: I ran indexOf('\ufffd') on the string and it is not -1, what encoding would you say it is then?  And what should I do to salvage this situation?

Comment: @Yongke: That doesn't tell us anything about the encoding - it just suggest that you're losing information, which doesn't surprise me. You should really tackle the problem at its root, but we don't know enough context to say more.

Comment: what if you have this kind of string that you want to convert to byte array

[70, 77, 82, 0, 32, 50, 48, 0, 1, 34, 0, -61,-77, 4, 0, 0]

Comment: @ralphspoon: Then you would remove the square brackets, split on strings, and parse each byte's decimal representation. This is not really an encoding issue.

Comment: @JonSkeet what im expecting to happen is to get that string as a byte[] format. can you provide an example ?

Comment: @ralphspoon: Not in comments, no - basically the question you're asking is unrelated to the question you've attached the comment to. I suspect if you look hard you may well find it's been asked on Stack Overflow already, but if not, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

If it really is that your String contains binary data that was just erroneously put into a string instead of a byte-array, then there is quite a simple method of conversion:

```
byte[] target = new byte[lob.length()];
for(int i = 0; i < lob.length(); i++)
    target[i] = (byte)lob.charAt(i);
```

If this data is somehow textual, however, then Jon Skeet's answer is the right one.

(This is, by the way, the same as ISO-8859-1 encoding.)

Comment: ISO-8859-1 will turn characters > 255 to be `?`

Comment: @PeterLawrey, well, it's true that ISO-8859-1 will error out on those instead of converting them, but assuming it is as OP described that this is just binary data mistakenly put into a string, there will be no such in here anyway, so under the premises, they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Strings use UTF-16 encoding and to avoid conversion you can use this encoding and each 16-bit character is basic sent as is.

Assuming you are in a Little-Endian environment

```
out.write(lob.getBytes(StandardCharset.UTF_16LE));
```

All valid characters will be send without further encoding.

Note: binary data should not be stored in Strings unless you really know it safe to do this as not all 16-bit values are valid characters. A better way to store binary data is to use bytes.

Comment: How do I tell which encoding it is?  I tried indexOf('\ufffd') and it is not -1, so does this mean it is UTF8 or UTF16?

Comment: @YongkeBillYu What are you referring to which you ask "which encoding it is"

Comment: The string is from a image file so it must had been converted from binary.  But I don't know what encoding it is.  Or I was going to decode it to get the original data.

Comment: @YongkeBillYu  Storing binary in a String is not very sound as you can have character corrupted if they are not valid.  Is there any way to keep the binary as binary as once the data is corrupted there is no way to reverse it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree 100% with Jon Skeet. I'll add that Java does an implicit conversion of any String data to UTF-16, however that implicit conversion comes on top of an explicit conversion which was done by whoever is passing you that data (wether they know it or not), so using getBytes("UTF-16") isn't automatically going to work either, unless they state otherwise or you've checked so by yourself.

Knowing where that data comes from and what encoding it is in is the only way to convert it back properly.